# Many to many crud using entity framework 4.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

My view submits data to the controller using Json objects which contains child objects.It allows users to add/remove/modify the relationship with child entities(authors,categories,LIbraryBookCopy). Users can only select authors and categories from list but can update/add LibraryBookCopy object.

This is my first MVC project and I have done this so far . Am I doing too much manipulation on the data? Is this the right way of doing this?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(BookViewModel bookv)
    {
        bool found=false;
        Mapper.CreateMap<AuthorViewModel, Author>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryViewModel, Category>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<LibraryBookCopyViewModel, LibraryBookCopy>();
        List<Author> authors = Mapper.Map<List<AuthorViewModel>, List<Author>>(bookv.Authors.ToList());
        List<Category> categories = Mapper.Map<List<CategoryViewModel>, List<Category>>(bookv.Categories.ToList());
        bookv.Authors.Clear();
        bookv.Categories.Clear();
        Mapper.CreateMap< BookViewModel,Book>();
        Book  book = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel,Book>(bookv);
        List<LibraryBookCopy> toBeDeletedLibraryBookCopies = new List<LibraryBookCopy>();
        List<LibraryBookCopy> toBeAddedLibraryBookCopies = new List<LibraryBookCopy>();
        List<LibraryBookCopy> toBeUpdatedLibraryBookCopies = new List<LibraryBookCopy>();

        List<LibraryBookCopy> libraryBookCopiesFromDatabase = new List<LibraryBookCopy>();
       db.Books.Attach(book);

        //Assign categories to book
       foreach (Category c in categories)    { db.Categories.Attach(c); }

       book.Categories.Clear();

       foreach (Category c in categories)    { book.Categories.Add(c); }

     //Assign authors to book
     foreach (Author a in authors)           { db.Authors.Attach(a);   }

      book.Authors.Clear();

            foreach (Author a in authors)    {book.Authors.Add(a); }

            if (bookv.LibraryBookCopies != null)
            {
                List<LibraryBookCopy> bookCopiesFromView = Mapper.Map<List<LibraryBookCopyViewModel>, List<LibraryBookCopy>>(bookv.LibraryBookCopies);

                libraryBookCopiesFromDatabase = db.LibraryBookCopies.Where(lbc=>lbc.BookId==book.BookId).ToList();

                foreach (LibraryBookCopy bc in libraryBookCopiesFromDatabase)
                {
                    foreach (LibraryBookCopy bcv in bookCopiesFromView)
                    {
                        if ((bc.LibraryId == bcv.LibraryId) )
                        {
                            found = true;
                            toBeUpdatedLibraryBookCopies.Add(bcv);
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    if (!found)
                    {
                       toBeDeletedLibraryBookCopies.Add(bc);
                    }
                    found = false;
                }

                //remove objects moved to toBeDelted

                foreach (LibraryBookCopy lbc in toBeDeletedLibraryBookCopies )
                {

                    libraryBookCopiesFromDatabase.Remove(lbc);
                }

                //NOW FIND NEW BOOK COPIES TO BE ADDED
                foreach (LibraryBookCopy bcv in bookCopiesFromView)
                {
                    if (libraryBookCopiesFromDatabase.Count == 0)
                    {
                        toBeAddedLibraryBookCopies.Add(bcv);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        foreach (LibraryBookCopy bc in libraryBookCopiesFromDatabase)
                        {
                            if ((bc.LibraryId != bcv.LibraryId))
                            {

                                toBeAddedLibraryBookCopies.Add(bcv);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            else
            {
                book.LibraryBookCopies.Clear();
            }

        //mark copies as deleted
        foreach (LibraryBookCopy lbcv in toBeDeletedLibraryBookCopies)
        {
          //  db.LibraryBookCopies.Attach(lbcv);
           db.LibraryBookCopies.DeleteObject(lbcv);
        }

        //Add library ref to each libraryBookCopies object in Book
        foreach (LibraryBookCopy lBC in toBeAddedLibraryBookCopies)
        {
            db.LibraryBookCopies.AddObject(lBC);
        }
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(book, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing too much on the `Controller` is subjective. If you do not have a Data Access Layer, I guess this is where you have to write this manipulation logic. However, you can consider followings;

- Pick meaningful names which are intention-revealing and pronounceable instead of encoding (such as `bookv`, `c`, `a`, `bc`, `bcv`, `lBC`).
- Split methods so they are small enough to one thing and give descriptive names. In this way you obey to do '*method should do one and one only thing*' and *not to do anything that is not useful for the program*.

You can start doing these by;

1. Rename variables for meaningful names.
2. Move mapping logic to a seperate method.
3. Move each `FOREACH`/`IF` statements to separate methods.
4. Encapsulate `IF` conditions from methods.
5. Encapsulate body content of `FOREACH`/`IF` statements to separate methods.
6. Encapsulate LINQ queries using filters.
7. Encapsulate object's state change from a method.

However, doing all these could be over engineering so you might need to find the balance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in C#, so just two generic notes:

1. The following comments are good candidates for method names:

   - `//Assign categories to book`: `assignCategories`, `assignCategoriesToBook`
   - `//Assign authors to book`: `assignAuthors`, `assignAuthorsToBook`
   - `//remove objects moved to toBeDelted`: `removeObjects`
   - `//NOW FIND NEW BOOK COPIES TO BE ADDED`: `findNewBooks`
   - `//mark copies as deleted`: `markDeleted`
   - `//Add library ref to each libraryBookCopies object in Book`: `addLibraryReference`
2. Short variable names (like `lBC`, `lbcv`, `bcv`, `bookv`) are not too readable. I suppose you have autocomplete, so using longer names does not mean more typing but I'd help readers and maintainers a lot since they don't have to remember the purpose of each variable - the name would express the programmers intent.